# Identificar se o app está em background ou apenas trocou de activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Tem alguma maneira de determinar se o app foi para background ou apenas se ele trocou de activity?

Comment: Não domino muito android, mas creio que você precise criar um serviço para isso, por causa do ciclo de vida das activities, somente por elas acredito que não seja possível.

Comment: mas como fazer este serviço saber que o app está em background ou apenas trocou para outra activity?

Comment: obrigado pela indicação, não havia visto esta pergunta